# Can you copy table data from one table to another without specifying column lists?

Tags: sql, firebird

I have a table "table1"

```
table
id     -- lots of constraints and relationsships with other tables
name
job
```

If I create another table "table2"

```
table2
id   -- removed all the CONSTRAINTS autogenerated column related to the table and etc
name
job
```

Does this do the job to clone the data?

```
insert into table2 select * from table1
```

I want to use this short syntax because the table has hundreds of columns. If I specify them one by one the chance of mistake is very high. I used the DDL of table1 to create table2, and I only removed the constraints so that the table1 data can "enter" smoothly into table2. I also executed the query locally and it worked apparently, but I like to research more.

Comment: why do you think that restraints a re copied, do oyu get an error when you add the same data again or a value that is nit in the other tables
?

Comment: @nbk The OP doesn't ask if the constraints are copied.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel i ask if he gets an error when he runs his query, which is a vital detail for the question

Comment: @nbk The question says _"I also executed the query locally and it worked apparently"_, I interpret it as asking if this indeed works (which it does, but is IMHO generally not a good idea).

Comment: Database normalization is aimed to de-duplication of data in a database. Copying of data into the same database is duplication and thus denormalization that smells and often backfire. You must be very sure that your true goal worth it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```sql
insert into table2 select * from table1
```

Then it works as if you used

```sql
insert into table2 (<list-of-columns-table2>) select <list-of-columns-table1> from table1
```

Where:

- `<list-of-columns-table2>` are the columns of `TABLE2` in the order of the `RDB$FIELD_POSITION` column of [`RDB$RELATION_FIELDS`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref25/fblangref-appx04-relfields.html) for that table. This will match the order of columns as specified the `CREATE TABLE` statement, unless you modified it with [`ALTER TABLE`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref25/fblangref25-ddl-tbl.html#fblangref25-ddl-tbl-alter)
- Similarly, `<list-of-columns-table1>` are the columns of `TABLE1` in the order of the `RDB$FIELD_POSITION` column of `RDB$RELATION_FIELDS` for that table.

So, yes, your statement will work as you expect and copy all the data, but it comes with a number of caveats:

- `TABLE2` cannot have any `COMPUTED BY` or `GENERATED ALWAYS AS` columns (including Firebird 3.0 identity columns), because you cannot insert or update those columns. Note that Firebird 4.0 gives you an option to "overwrite" identity columns with the `OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE` clause
- Doing this is very fragile, if any column is added or removed, or the position of columns is altered in one table but not the other (or otherwise diverge), things will either break, or - worse - silently populate the wrong columns.
- This also applies if you use outdated (or different) DDL (i.e. the DDL you use for `TABLE2` doesn't actually match the columns or order of columns for the current version of `TABLE1`).

In short, for one-off or maybe short term needs to copy data this is probably acceptable, but for long term or repeated use it is better to write out all columns, or use something to *generate* the needed query with all columns in the right order (and maybe detect missing columns, mismatches in column types and lengths, etc).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM TabLe1
```

is the same as

```
SELECT id,name,job FROM table1
```

If your table1 has onl these three columns.

we don't recommended using * as in ten 10 fyears rom now, you don't know what you actually wanted from the query, that is of course with three columns not  that tragic, but with 50 it gets interesting.

So `SELECT *`  is only a bad habit and not recommended, but it yields no other negative aspects see also https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list